# Motion Tracking Render - Invisible object in render

Tags: rendering

I've setup a motion tracking scene with trackers, background etc.. 
I have 2 objects in my scene: a cube that renders without problem, and an imported rig. 
That imported rig does not appear in the render, but its shadow is present.
I have checked the layers, the texture.. 
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: maybe it's on layer 2, try moving to layer 1 -select and press M 1- that's how blender sets up a tracking scene, objects in layer 1 and shadows on layer 2

Comment: I've finally solved the problem ! Thank you for your answer anyway. It was because an object was in Blender Cycles, I've just converted it into Blender Internal and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved the problem ! Thank you for your answer anyway. It was because an object was in Blender Cycles, I've just converted it into Blender Internal and it worked like a charm.